# Why can't we see when we last voted a question by hovering the vote arrows?

Tags: feature-request, voting

This is a fairly small request, but every so often I find myself looking at an answer that I already had voted on in the past. Whenever I do see that I previously voted an answer I like to click on the vote arrow to see when I last voted on the question, and I get a message like this:

> You last voted on this answer 01/01/0001. Your vote is now
>   locked in unless this answer is edited.

I like seeing when I last voted something because it can help me recall what I was working on when I last voted the answer and help me understand how I implemented that answer to fix my problem... or I see that I last voted on it year(s) ago and should probably use due diligence and make sure that the solution I voted is still a good viable solution.

The problem with clicking on the arrow like that is that questions and answers inevitably get edited, and then when I click on it I remove my vote, and have to revote (if appropriate). I was never able to see my original vote date in this scenario.

I'm wondering why we can't just change the `title` text that currently says:

> This answer is useful (click again to undo)

To something like this:

> This answer is useful (click again to undo). Last voted: 01/01/0001

Comment: Hmm... Wouldnt putting it on the hover means every time I load a question where I have voted at some point, a request to grab the time of my vote is sent to the server, as opposed to only fetching this if I click? All in all, depending on the underlying data structure, might be a pretty big issue

Comment: @Patrice That's a good call, I didn't think of that. I suppose if that's the case the price may not be worth the reward.

Comment: Mind you,I am playing devil's advocate. I actually think it should be implemented, if feasible.

Comment: The StackAPI doesn't have this time info and having it send as part of the page html would be a major blow to page caching. You have to go over your [votes tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=downvote) in your profile to find the exact time of your votes for a post. That does require you have to find the post first. If you're a prolific voter that can be a long list to search ..

Comment: Note that the accepted check has the tooltip “loading when this answer was accepted...” when you hover it, then it does some AJAX and changes the tooltip to “The question owner accepted this as the best answer <time string>.”

Comment: The tooltip is generated in the html, no need for ajax. Now, there are that many people that care about when they voted instead that they just voted.

Comment: @Patrice The system already retrieves your vote to display it so it would just need to retrieve the timestamp alongside. Probably a negligible overhead.

Comment: @DidierL likely,yes. But the structure COULD be more complex than that. We don't know their structure so I was just saying it MIGHT be more complex than we all think. If all was well designed, then you are right.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355868/can-i-see-when-i-voted-on-a-question) In the discussion there, I was wondering if I should make this very feature request

Comment: @CDspace I think it's something that should be requested... This just happened to me (twice) yesterday when I was looking up something I hadn't done for a year or two. I clicked the arrow and both posts had been edited so I lost the time stamp information. I really like to see when I voted on something because if it was a long time ago in a galaxy far, far away then I should probably spend the extra time looking into some newer answers - not that you shouldn't always do that, but time doesn't always permit it.

Comment: I learned a new term today in language X, searched to see why that didn't exist in language Y, found an SO post... marked with my up-votes.  I'd really like to know when I did that and I have too many votes to search through.

Comment: This would be possible to achieve user-side with a userscript that scrapes your vote history, but it would take a *bunch* of requests to build the local database for those who've voted a lot. Upside would be that said expensive scraping would only have to happen once, if you don't clear your browser cache

Comment: This would be super cool. I'm always coming across stuff again that I've been to before and been like "huh, I was already here?! When?" :)